# Vmnet8 Interface is not forwarding packets to the vm

Tags: virtualization, vmware, nat

I have a vm connected to the vmnet 8 interface. I cannot reach the virtual machine from my host but it can reach the host from the vm. When i trace to the vm i see the host is sending the packet to the gw of the physical machine. I checked the routing table which is ok. I restarted all the services. Nothing works. Do you have a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Please give us more information, IP addresses, routing table etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try accessing by IP address (VMnet8 is NAT) and if that does not work, reset the NAT setup using the VMware Network Editor. Restart and test again.

Comment: I got to my machine with a Windows guest (easier than Linux) and accessing the VM (on VMnet8) from Windows 10 using NET USE  to map a drive works fine.

Comment: Ip address of host 192.168.1.58

Comment: Vm host 192.168.60.131 vm adaptor 192.168.60.1 routes --- 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1 --- 192.168.60.0/24 gw 192.168.60.1

Comment: Your NAT IP looks correct (totally different subnet from the Host) but you should be able to access by IP address.

Comment: I know but i cant. maybe a hard reset to the pc will help

Comment: Reset the NAT interface with the VMware Network Editor and then Reset the host computer as I suggested earlier.